# Prove a group action

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field of size $q$. Define a map $GL_n(\mathbb{F}) \times \mathbb{F}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}:$

$P \cdot M=PMP^{-1}, P\in GL_n(\mathbb{F}), M \in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$.

I need to show that the map is a group action.

Showing the identity condition is trivial, but I have problems with proving compatibility, i.e.

$P \cdot (R \cdot M)=P\cdot RMR^{-1} = PRMR^{-1}P^{-1}$

$(PR)\cdot M=(PR)M(PR)^{-1}$

and I can't figure out how to prove the equality $PRMR^{-1}P^{-1} = (PR)M(PR)^{-1}$.

Comment: You need $(PR)^{-1}=R^{-1}P^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but where does it follow from?

Comment: The definition of inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to use the fact that $(PR)^{-1} = R^{-1} P^{-1}$. This is easy to see, since
$$ \begin{aligned}
PR (R^{-1} P^{-1}) &= P (R R^{-1}) P^{-1} \\
&= P I P^{-1}\\
&= P P^{-1}\\
&= I
\end{aligned}$$

Since $R^{-1} P^{-1}$ un-does $PR$, it must be its inverse.